# How can I get the duration of played video with FFMPEG?

Tags: actionscript-3, ffmpeg, air

I'm using FFMPEG to play a video (as I needed to allow for .avi and .mov formats) and currently cannot find a way to get the duration of the video. If I wasn't using FFMPEG it would be simple enough using onMetaData but this returns 0 as FFMPEG requires `netStream.play(null);` instead of `netStream.play(videoPath);`.

The function I am looking to add into to check for the video's duration:

```
nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData);

public function onOutputData(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    var videoStream:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    nativeProcess.standardOutput.readBytes(videoStream, 0, nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable);
    netStream.appendBytes(videoStream);
}
```

Comment: I edited your question to include this change. You can do such edits yourself by clicking "edit" below your question. On StackOverflow, you should always add new information by editing your question and not put it all into the comments. The question should always contain all the information. It's tedious to search the comments for important information. Editing is very encouraged. You can (and should!) even edit questions or answers of other users if you see fit (just like I did with yours)

Comment: +1 for the onMetaData mention.. You were already close to helping yourself but didnt know for sure. Somehow I also missed that part before but I see it now on re-reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (another way you could try..) :**

When NetStream plays a video it first checks for metadata, and since the FLV metadata holds a **duration** entry you could try read that (metadata is always sent in for appending first before any actual video frames data)...

**1)** *Declare a public var to listen out for metadata*

```
public var metaListener : Object;
```

**2)** *Setup the Meta listener when you also setup your NetStream*

```
nc = new NetConnection();   nc.connect(null);
metaListener = new Object();
metaListener = { onMetaData: received_Meta };
ns = new NetStream(nc); ns.client = metaListener;
```

**3)** *The "received Meta" function triggered by above "onMetaData"*

```
public function received_Meta ( v_data : Object ) : void
{
    trace("video duration   : "  + v_data.duration );
}
```

or alternatively to auto-list every available entry in the metadata

```
public function received_Meta ( v_data : Object ) : void
{
    trace("### Begin Metadata listing : FLV Entries ### "  );
        for (var entry:* in v_data) 
        {
            var value:Object = v_data[ entry ];
            trace(" > " + entry + " : " + value);
        }
    trace("### End of Metadata listing for this FLV ### "  );
}
```

Comment: Although I already marked the answer above as the correct answer, this answer works better for me even though it does require waiting on the buffer to finish. Thank you.

Comment: No worries about that. You asked for **"..With FFMPEG"** and you got the FFMPEG way to do it. I'm just showing how to achieve it from within AS3 side only. Since one tool makes the file and the other tool plays, they are both aware of same information... PS I added new edit.. It occured to me that by the time FLV plays, AS3 is already aware of its duration. I should have thought of that first!!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the duration of your video using `ffmpeg` and `NativeProcess` :

```
var video:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('video.avi'),
    exe:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('ffmpeg.exe');

if (NativeProcess.isSupported) {

    var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
        args.push("-i", video.nativePath);

    var npsi:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
        npsi.executable = exe;
        npsi.arguments = args;

    var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();        
        process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_ERROR_DATA, on_output_data);
        process.start(npsi);

    function on_output_data(e:ProgressEvent):void {
        var s:String = process.standardError.readUTFBytes(process.standardError.bytesAvailable);
        var a:Array = s.match(/Duration: (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/) || [];
        if(a.length > 0){
            trace('video duration :', a[1]);    
            // gives for example : video duration : 00:01:45
        }   
    }

} else {

    trace('NativeProcess is not supported');

}
```

You can also use [`ffprobe`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration) like this :

```
var exe:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath('ffprobe.exe');

var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
    args.push('-v', 'error', '-show_entries', 'format=duration', '-of', 'default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1', video.nativePath);

var npsi:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
    npsi.executable = exe;
    npsi.arguments = args;

var process:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();        
    process.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, on_output_data);
    process.start(npsi);

function on_output_data(e:ProgressEvent):void
{       
    trace('video duration :', process.standardOutput.readUTFBytes(process.standardOutput.bytesAvailable));
    // gives for example : video duration : 67.250584
}
```

Hope that can help.